# How to reuse the same function in multiple policy files

Tags: laravel

This function will be used by many policies. How to avoid writing this inside each policy file?

```
public function checkRoleAndPermission($name)
{
    $content = 'Location';

    $permission = Permission::where([['content', $content], ['name', $name]])->first();
    if(empty($permission))
        return false;

    return auth()->user()->hasRole($permission->roles);
}
```

Comment: You could create a BasePolicy and extend all others from it

Comment: I created BasePolicy and that worked for me. Thanks. Could you please post this as an answer so that I can tick mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practice would be to create an `BasePolicy` and extend all others from it

Example

```php
class BasePolicy 
{
    public function checkRoleAndPermission($name)
    {
        $content = 'Location';

        $permission = Permission::where([['content', $content], ['name', $name]])->first();
        if(empty($permission))
            return false;

        return auth()->user()->hasRole($permission->roles);
    }
}
```

````php
class PostPolicy extends BasePolicy
{
    public function update(User $user, Post $post, $rolePermission)
    {
        $this->checkRoleAndPermission($rolePermission);
        ...
    }
}
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Create a class with the above function 'checkRoleAndPermission'.
Wherever need, extend the class and reuse the function like below.

Class A:

```
public class A{

    public function checkRoleAndPermission($name)
    {
        $content = 'Location';

        $permission = Permission::where([['content', $content], ['name', $name]])->first();
        if(empty($permission)) return false;

        return auth()->user()->hasRole($permission->roles);
    }
}
```

Class B:

```
use A;
public class B extends A{
    $this->checkRoleAndPermission('name'); // it will call class A's checkRoleAndPermission() function
}
```